# Using Scala reflection to find most derived runtime type

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm trying to use Scala 2.10 reflection to find the most derived type of a method argument. For example, consider this program:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

object ReflectionTest {

  def checkType[A : TypeTag](item: A) {
    println("typeOf[A]: " + typeOf[A])
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val a = Array(1, "Hello")
    for (item <- a) checkType(item)
  }
}
```

Here `a` has type Array[Any] so each item being sent to `checkType` has type Any. As a result, `checkType` outputs

```
typeOf[A]: Any
typeOf[A]: Any
```

This makes sense to me since the TypeTag is generated by the compiler at the point of the call (where all it knows about the type is that it is `Any`). What I want, however, is to determine the actual type of each item. I'd like output something along the lines of

```
Int
String
```

I have looked over the documentation here

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html

but the samples don't seem to cover this case and I find the discussion there of Environments, Universes, and Mirrors difficult to penetrate. It seems like what I'm trying to do should be fairly simple but perhaps I'm approaching it completely wrong.

Comment: you cannot retrieve un-erased types from reflection without some kind of compile-time info (type tags) since only erased types exist at runtime on the JVM, so @tenshi's answer is the best you can do. The only way to go beyond that would be to store a type tag for each element of your array in another data structure alongside this one.

Answer (score 7):

Most obvious solution would be to use the class:

```
def checkType[A](item: A) {
  println("typeOf[A]: " + item.getClass)
}
```

But if you want to work with `Type`, then some additional work is needed:

```
def checkType[A](item: A) {
  val mirror = runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
  println("typeOf[A]: " + mirror.classSymbol(item.getClass).toType)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @tenshi, that's helpful. I'm actually trying to do this with arrays. I notice your solution appears to be returning erased types. I also need to access the element type of the array. I'm not sure if there's an easy fix... I will continue digging.